# Bootstrap fullwidth container background-image redcution based on screen size via media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am trying to display a smaller background-image version for mobile devices using media queries. However, the original background image is displayed regular size behind the reduced image.
[image]
Here is the css for the image in regular form.

```
#signup{
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),
image-url('zoom1028.jpg');
background-position: center center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #464646;
height: 800px;
}
```

Here are the bootstrap media queries in same css.scss file that I am using.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
 #signup{ 
 background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),
 image-url('zoom1028.jpg');
 background-position: center center; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: fixed;
 background-size: cover;  
 }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
#signup{ 
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),
image-url('zoom1028.jpg');
background-position: center center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: fixed;
background-size: cover;  
 }
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
#signup{ 
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)),
image-url('zoom1028.jpg');
background-position: center center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: fixed;
background-size: cover;  
 }
}
```

Comment: You have different selectors. `#signup` and `#signupcopy`.

Comment: Show us the HTML, and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) will help too.